# Can descriptive sentences be used with JavaScript constants where only uniqueness matters?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, constants

My Chrome Extension uses a number of constants, specifically for [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). For example a message sender may have:

```
var message = {
  from: 'content', 
  subject: 'dataReady', 
  data: data
};

var port = chrome.runtime.connect({
  name: 'main'
});

port.postMessage(message);
```

Constants used by message sender are: **content**, **dataReady** and **main**. The message receiver makes similar use of constants:

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if ((msg.from === 'content') && 
      (msg.subject === 'dataReady')) {  
        // Do something with data 
        // ... in msg.data
    }
}
```

Constants used by message receiver are: **content** and **dataReady**. The message receiver would also use the constant **main** should it send a reply.

The value of these constants is **unimportant** to the extent that they must only be unique and have some broadly meaningful value to the programmer. My Chrome extension also uses more 'traditional' constants where value is meaningful, e.g. `var MAX_AGE = 30;`.

To prevent cluttering up the global namespace with constants, I have a JavaScript object containing all my constants, grouped logically and saved in a separate `constants.js` file:

```
var constants { 
  'actors' : {
    // Content script embedded on site foo.com.
    'content' : 'content',
    // Extension UI loaded when icon clicked.
    'popup' : 'doActionB'
  },
  'subjects' : {
    // The content script has finished loading data.
    'dataReady' : 'dataReady',
    // The content script has refreshed data from user.
    'updateReady' : 'updateReady'
  },
  'channels' : {
    // Main channel used for messaging.
    'main' : 'main'
   },
  'MAX_AGE' : 30,
}
```

...which is then used throughout my Chrome extension:

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if ((msg.from === constants.actors.content) && 
      (msg.subject === constants.subjects.dataReady)) {  
        // Do something with data 
        // ... in msg.data
    }
}
```

Great, so all my constants are in one place in a separate file with comments.

I then thought perhaps I could make better use of my constant values by making them more descriptive:

```
var constants { 
  'actors' : {
    'content' : 'Content script embedded on site foo.com.',
    'popup' : 'Extension UI loaded when icon clicked.'
  },
  'subjects' : {
    'dataReady' : 'The content script has finished loading data.',
    'updateReady' : 'The content script has refreshed data from user.'
  },
  'channels' : {
    'main' : 'Main channel used for messaging.'
   },
  'MAX_AGE' : 30,
}
```

This prevents the need for comments and since the values of these constants is irrelevant, I should be OK.

Question: Is this a bad idea, a bad practice or is there a better way?

**Updated** to include the accepted answer provided by @Basic. I particularly like the solution since it allows the unimportance of the value to be emphasized with clearly incrementing integer values.  Only downside was that channel names must be strings.

```
var constants = {    
    'actors' : {
    // Content script embedded on site foo.com.
    'content' : 1,
    // Extension UI loaded when icon clicked.
    'popup' : 2
    },
    'subjects' : {
    // The content script has finished loading data.
    'dataReady' : 1,
    // The content script has refreshed data from user.
    'updateReady' : 2
    },
    'channels' : {
    'main' : 'main'
    },
    'MAX_AGE' : 30,
}
```

Comment: Comparing string constants will take slightly more time to resolve than integers since each character in each string will be checked.  However, if it isn't done very often it won't really be noticeable.  If done in a loop where speed is crucial you will likely see some slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to dislike the latter implementation for a couple of reasons:

- It's ambiguous in that there's no way to differentiate constants with important values and those with arbitrary descriptions.
- That may not matter much but it exacerbates my second objection; It's far too susceptible to copy/paste errors. Anyone glancing at the code would assume that the key is important and must be unique. It's far less clear that a free-text description must be unique. If you ever do have 2 constants with the same value, the errors would be subtle, remote from the source of the problem and hard to debug.
- I'm not sure how/where your constants are used but it may involve transmitting/storing a more data than necessary. There may be database column width issues.
- Descriptions are more likely to update than constants. Might this pose an upgrade issue when reading old data?

That's not to say you shouldn't use a complex self-documenting structure with a "description" attribute if you want one, but I'd keep the value used for comparison short and predictable.

Comment: I like this approach. By using deliberately meaningless integer values for constants, it documents an important feature: namely that the values are unimportant.